# Are spark workers/jvm (re)started for each spark application?

Tags: apache-spark

Simple question for which I didn't find an answer. I think I saw somewhere that the worker/jvm processes are started for each spark application, but don't remember where. Also I would be very surprised if they didn't. But I would like to be sure.

Comment: Jvm is not restarted for every job. As long as the cluster is running the jvm is running. For dynamic executor jvms would change as executors are added or removed

Comment: A spark job is a DAG that has input, a few stages and output. The RDD are related to a single sparkContext, so are the jobs. In this way, RDD from the previous job can be used in the next job. Once the sparkContext is deleted, everything will lost.

Comment: You're sure? It would be unsafe if some transformation fill up some static cache, for example, not restarting would mean all later job would be get this cache. There is also the question of classloader that could fill up memory, but I would expect spark to manage that smoothly.

Comment: You've got an interesting point about sharing spark context. However, how are spark context shared between multiple job?

Comment: Are you interested in any execution engine in particular, or you want answers for all of them?

Comment: Does it matter which engine?

Comment: Aaaah!! I just checked and I used the wrong word: I meant spark application, not job :-\